# Trying to define an input to match a randomly generated number

Tags: python

Here is my code for guessing a randomly generated number.  On line 16 (if input("what number did I think of"...) is where it keeps reading a syntax error.  I want the user to guess the number and see if it matches up with "number" from line 14.  Where am I going wrong?

```
fname = input("Hey what's your first name? : ")
lname = input("Ok, what's your Last Name? : ")
print ("Hello  " + fname + " " + lname)

if (input('Want to play a game called Guess the Number?') == "yes" or "Yes" or "sure" or "Sure" or "ok" or "Ok" or "OK"):
    print("Ok, Great!  The rules are simple; I am going to randomly think of a number and then you try and guess it.  If you get it right, then you win the game.  If not, I will give you up to five mathematical clues and you keep guessing.") 
else:
    print("Ok, later!") 
    exit()

print("Ok, here we go! I just thought of a number.")

import random
number=random.randint(0,100)

if (input("What number did I think of?") == number)
    print("Wow, good guess. You got it!  Let's play again some other time!")
    exit()
else:
    print("Nope, thats not it.  Here is my first clue:")
```

Comment: You forgot the `:` at the end of the `if`...

Comment: for it to work properly, you have to typecast either `number` to string or your input to `int`, before comparing , `int(input("What number did I think of?")) == number:` or `input("What number did I think of?") == str(number):`

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
if (input("What number did I think of?") == number)
```

To:

```
if input("What number did I think of?") == number:
```

You can't format python code like what you did.

Answer (score 1):

Change this time:

```
if (input("What number did I think of?") == number)
```

To:

```
int(input("What number did I think of?")) == number:
```